# Copy access db to sql using ssms

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have copied a Access db to sql using the import and export tool. It all goes well and there are no errors, but when I try to view tables in SSMS, there are no tables there. Where does the tool put these dbo files and do I have to do any extra work to use this database. I am a complete novice to sql. My background is php/mysql so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you sure you havent imported them tables into Master Database. When you were importing data did you select the right destination Database ?? and sometimes even when the tables have been imported you cant see them until you refresh the tables folder in SSMS.

Comment: @Muhammed I double checked everything and refreshed table folder. Thanks